# Jsoup unable to load URL using Groovy

Tags: groovy, web-scraping, jsoup

I am unable to load https://www.abc.ca.gov/datport/lqs.html?rpttype=5 this URL using Java/Groovy to extract information from this webpage. It inloves Request using POST method. Please help to resolve.
Using InteliJIdea and Groovy.

Comment: Please, could you edit your question in order to include your code, as well as the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi , there is no such error message I am getting it just loads the home page of website instead the desired page. I can share the Html I am receiving

Answer (score 0):

JSoup and Groovy can easily load the page using this:

```
@Grab('org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.1')

// The URL to scrape
String url = "https://www.abc.ca.gov/datport/lqs.html?rpttype=5"
// Connect and get URL via Jsoup
def doc = org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(url).get()

// Output the entire HTML page
println doc
```

The table displayed on the page is retrieved with Ajax, and to retrieve that, you would need to parse the JSON from the request made with Javascript.

It might be easier for you to try using Geb, which can wait for the page beeing loaded with data, and then you can scrape it.

Comment: Thanks for your response can you please send something using GEB, I am new to this. If you can send sample code that would be very useful for me.